# Any easy-to-use Machine Learning application?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

I would like a general machine learning solution that allows me to input any kind of data in it, and it gives me a list of all the informations it learned about the data. For example, I could input a website's browsing information and it gives me statements about the data eg. "users between 18-25 are more likely to visit XY subpage" or "native English speakers spend an average XY sec more time on the website".

I want it to be as general as possible, and easy to learn and use. It could be a free software or an API in Java / C++ / Matlab.

Comment: Node-Red + IBM Watson is easy to use, but it doesn't run in your machine and I don't know if it's still free. [AzureML](https://studio.azureml.net/) is also easy to use, but also online.

Comment: AzureML looks useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AzureML](https://studio.azureml.net/) is an easy-to-use machine learning solution. It runs on Microsoft servers and features a drag and drop interface. Supports programming via Python and R. It has a free tier with usage limits (time, nodes, disk usage and availability of API). It's perfect to start doing Machine Learning experiments.
[image: AzureML Studio]